# Compare a value of a column with mean of that column SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  country CHARACTER VARYING(40),
  city CHARACTER VARYING(40),
  population NUMERIC(10,6) DEFAULT NULL::numeric
);
```

What I want is to get country, city from the table where population is less than mean of the population.

like if I have data

```
id | country | city     | population
1  | US      | New York | 250
2  | US      | dalas    | 150
3  | UK      | london   | 300
4  | UK      | york     | 100
```

Average population is 200, so the query should list `US, dalas` and `UK, york` as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select * FROM T
where populuation< (SELECT AVG(population) FROM T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option which may perform better would be to use a CTE and a Window function, and a filter based on the output of that.

```
 WITH base_data as (SELECT t, avg(population) 
                              OVER (range unbounded preceding) as average
                      FROM t)
 SELECT (t).* from base_data where t.population < average;
```

You don't have to separate the row and aggregate data like I did (selecting the table type as a field and exploding it in the filtered query),  In fact if you don't mind returning the average also you could just:

```
 WITH base_data as (SELECT *, avg(population) 
                              OVER (range unbounded preceding) as average
                      FROM t)
 SELECT * from base_data where t.population < average;
```